# Admob native ads hangs UI

Tags: android, admob

I'm trying to populate my recyclerview with AdMob native ads and it works well and shows the ad. But the problem that I always have and it's driving me crazy is the hanging of the UI when loading and showing the ad. I have followed the guidelines for implementing the native ad as the docs say but still, it hangs UI

[Documentation](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/native/advanced)

[Github Example Kotlin](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-android-examples/tree/master/kotlin/admob/NativeAdvancedExample)

I've searched and found countless numbers of the same problem and I have never found a solution.

I'm writing the SO question and I may have a feeling it will be marked duplicate, but still just wanted an answer for myself.

Does Admob have a bug and is there a way to fix this hanging of UI?

Answer (score 0):

Just downgrade AdMob library version. It worked on my side.

Comment: To which version would that be?